# How can i Unit Test a single [Test] method in MonoDevelop?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, monodevelop

So i'm using `MonoDevelop` (for some `MonoTouch` R&D) and have a `Unit Testing class library` using `NUnit`.

I have a single [TestFixture] and a couple of [Test] classes. I can run all the tests in one single go .. but i have no idea how i can DEBUG (as in, breakpoint + step through) an individual one.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Did you come across with the below article?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34161/Setup-a-Test-Project-with-NUnit-and-MonoDevelop See the "Points of Interests"
and may be
http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Feb-19-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a regular *NUnit* test class library in *MonoDevelop*, you should be able to use the *Mono Soft Debugger* on individual tests.

In the *Unit Tests* tab, select the test that you want to debug and right-click on the test. Select **Run Test With > Mono Soft Debugger**:

[image]

Now, you should be able to step through the test code as desired:

[image]

This has been tested on a recent version, 3.0, of *MonoDevelop*.